# Multiple criteria formula should be returning multiple matches. But is only returning the first match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is the Function that should be returning a handful of matches:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!C2:C7, SMALL(IF(1=((--(B3=Data!U2:U7)) * (--(C3=Data!W2:W7))), ROW(Data!C2:C7)-2,""), ROW()-2)),"")`

B3 and C3 are both selections from Data Validation lists

It should result in a list of 3 items, but it is only returning a single match. The goal is to use the results of this formula as the basis for a Data Validation list based on multiple selections of options.

[Link to the Testbed Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-1EUTWAhYiPYsHnUkNKtTOspu5Lvz-4R)

Comment: So you want to pull down down the formula to get all results? In that case you need to make the cell references absolute (e. g. `$B$3=Data!$U$2:$U$7`). Currently your cell references are moving in the direction you are pulling the formula.

Comment: So the mistake I'm making is assuming the formula will Spill?

Comment: with `ROW()-2` you are only bringing in one value.  If you have the dynamic array formula with a subscription to Office 365 you can make it spill by putting in an array `{1,2,3,4}` this will return the first 4.